# Как реализовать запуск скрипта sh-cgi-py в html

Tags: python, html, linux, sh, cgi

Появилась потребность в создании удаленного подключения к множественным компьютерам, с одного ПК.
Для тестов выбрал астру, так как идет переход на отечественное ПО.
Что было сделано:
-развернут apache сервер, занесены необходимые правила, пути.
Удаленное подключение идет по VNC (vino) - установка на клиенте и на сервере - другой утилиты.
Скрипт через терминал работает, через графику тоже, а вот через браузер нет...
[image: Вот сам скрипт, который выводит время и дату (работает) + должен подключиться к клиенту ( не работает)]

[image: Основная страничка]

[image: Код основной странички]

Права на все папки и файлы - root, 755.

Comment: CGI устарел, Python 2 устарел, Vino устарел, Apache 2 устарел (в каком-то смысле)... Простите, а в этой астре не найдётся каких-нибудь более актуальных технологий?

Comment: А вообще не очень понятно, чего вы в принципе хотели добиться этим кодом. Чтобы `DISPLAY=:0 vncviewer` заработал, логично, что должен быть запущен X-сервер на том устройстве, на котором этот самый vncviewer запускается (то есть на сервере 192.168.0.103), и к браузеру это никакого отношения не имеет

Comment: @andreymal, я бы с радостью взялся бы за что-то более новое, но начальство настаивает на этой комбинации(
если это можно реализовать : веб-страничка - ссылки на адреса ( по клику осуществляется подключение ), я готов послушать, и если реально, то переубедить начальника..
сервер запущен на клиенте само собой (/usr/lib/vino-vino-server)
*скрипт отдельно, в терминале, работает отлично*

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы можно было подключаться к VNC-серверу непосредственно через браузер, то тогда, во-первых, нужен VNC-клиент, который способен работать собственно в браузере, а во-вторых, VNC-сервер должен быть способен принимать соединения по тем протоколам, с которыми способен работать браузер. В нормальном мире подобное организовывают с помощью [noVNC](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC) + [websockify](https://github.com/novnc/websockify), но возможно ли это завести в протухшей астре — не знаю...

Comment: @andreymal, а если исходить из того, что страничка будет только локальная на сервере, т.е. на ней будут размещены все адреса, куда нужно подключиться, а само подключение будет вызывать терминал, который и будет отрабатывать скрипт, такое возможно?

Comment: Такое возможно даже на древних технологиях

Comment: Питон 3 там какой версии? Я бы ответ написал)

Comment: Устаревший vino самый дружелюбный сервис. Единственный с дбас активацией.

Comment: @eri Питон - python 3.7.3